# Python - Parsing text in tsv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

I'm trying to get data in python from a tsv file but I still get this error :

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 23 fields in
>   line 3, saw 24

[This is my .tsv file](https://www.catupload.com/files/5ac362ed11c235257de6ad266b156388.tsv).

I'm using this command:

```
pd.read_table(tsv_file, delimiter="\t", encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Don't provide expiring links to your data but rather post the relevant part inline.